# Very basic JFrame not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I know that this question was asked many times and I've tried solutions mentioned there for last hour, but none of them worked for me. **I have very basic frame and it just doesn't show up**. No errors, after compilation just "Build succesful".

The whole code is:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame
{    
    public Frame()
    {
        super("Hello");
        this.setBounds(100, 500, 100, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Frame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html). Download and test the `FrameDemo` example. It show you the proper way to create Swing components. One key is that Swing components should be created on modified on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. If this code doesn't work then you probably have something wrong with your JDK. Try reinstalling.

Comment: FrameDemo from this page showed me alerts about Java version. Updated and did not helped, but another error about JDK occured. Installed the newest version from adoptopenjdk and frame is finally back. Thanks! Can you please repost it as answer to let me give your reply a tick?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Frame instance in main is from package java.awt.* which you have imported.
Check it out.

Comment: Good idea, but even if I changed package, class and constructor names from "Frame" to something else it's still not working.

Comment: I copied your code and it works fine by me. Only diff is the imported package I have only swing package.

Comment: Yes, java.awt is not used yet so removing it makes no difference at all. Strange, for me still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your program and the frame shows up fine for me. Couple of steps which you can try -

1. After running the program, you should check in task manager whether a new Java process is visible and if so, expand it and you should see "Hello", try bringing it to front (right click on process -> Bring to front).
2. From a code point of view, try adding `this.pack();` after `this.setDefaultCloseOperation` and re-run the program.

Comment: From a code point of view nothing works, but I think we found an issue. **I cannot see Java/jps process in task manager**. I tried to check java processes by `jps -l` in command line, but it shows only `2992 8716 jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jps.Jps` while as far as I understand it should show the frame process too if it's not set to close automatically. Do you know what I can do with this?

Comment: What happens if you comment out super("Hello"); and re-run the program ? Does the frame show up ?

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).

Download and test the FrameDemo example. It show you the proper way to create Swing components. One key is that Swing components should be created on modified on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

If this code doesn't work then you probably have something wrong with your JDK. Try reinstalling.